# How to wait browser on protractor e2e test?

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I have a flaky test. Its about my loading screen. I use

```
await browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(...)); // It contains parameters.

await browser.sleep(2000);
```

But still sometimes it is work , it is not. I have a button. My test try button click on Loading screen therefore it fail. It must wait when loading screen was gone.(I tried using wait and sleep )

How I do resolve the problem. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It must wait when loading screen was gone

1. Create a `while` loop.
2. Check if the loading screen is gone

   - if true then do your thing
   - else wait
3. Let the loop gets executed until the condition returns true

and by

> if the loading screen is gone

You can check the CSS of the element of the loading screen. It can be

```
display: none;
```

or

```
visibility: hidden;
```

depends on how it is hidden.

Comment: `var displayValue = await loadingPanel.getCssValue('display');
        while(displayValue !== 'none') {
            displayValue = await loadingPanel.getCssValue('display');
        }` @holydragon I tried but still flaky

Comment: I tried again using if else in while block. Its true. Thanks @holydragon

Comment: fyi: `browser.wait()` will create it's own while loop that will execute for a given amount of time or until the function you pass in resolves to true. If it does not resolve then within the specified time an exception will be throw. You could likely achieve the same functionality with something like `await browser.wait(async () => await loadingPanel.getCssValue('display') === 'none')` but I haven't tested this

Answer (score 0):

Just because your loading screen is invisible does not mean the the next page has is ready to interact with. You can try waiting for the visibility of an element on the next page or try changing your sleep to await browser.driver.sleep(2000).

I would probably take an element from the page you expect to be loaded and try

```
await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(reqElement), 5000,
   'reqElement not displayed on page after 5 seconds, loading screen may still be visible'
)
```